# Indexing specific values in a list to be changed based off a corresponding index

Tags: python, function, indexing

I have two arrays from previous functions

```
ALPt = (90, -70, 90)
N = [1, 2, 1]
```

I've defined a new function to do operations with each element in N but I want to set a condition based on the sign of the corresponding element in ALPt
I've tried a few different methods, this is the closest I have

```
def ALPe(): 
    ALPe = []
    for i in N:
        ALPe0 = math.degrees(math.acos((i * Bt) / (math.pi * Dk)))
        ALPe.append(ALPe0)
    for n, j in enumerate(ALPe):
        for m, k in enumerate(ALPt):
            if k < 0:
                ALPe[n] = j * -1
    return ALPe

ALPe = ALPe()
print(ALPe)
```

Output:

```
[-80.8421504880813, -71.43925528310385, -80.8421504880813]
```

I am missing something that changes the sign of the n element in ALPe based on m element in ALPt, which would make the output look like this:

```
[80.8421504880813, -71.43925528310385, 80.8421504880813]
```

any suggestions?

Comment: to simulate my output, Bt = 25 and Dk = 50

Comment: Why use the same variable name for both function and the list ?

Comment: This will happen only an only when `j` is positive which is not what the result shows. Also as @BcK mentioned don't use same name for your function and list.

Comment: without that for loop, all of js are positive. They all became negative when I added the conditional statement. Only the middle j should be negative.

Comment: So each element in `ALPe` should have the same sign as the element in `ALPt` at the same position?

Comment: that is the goal

Answer (score 0):

just looking at:

> So each element in ALPe should have the same sign as the element in
>   ALPt at the same position? – glibdud 1 hour ago
>
> that is the goal – chic9009

is this what is wanted?

```
a = [1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 4]
b = [4, -3, 2 , -1.0]

[abs(a)*((-1)**(b < 0)) for a, b in zip(a,b)]

Out[41]: [1.0, -2.0, 3.0, -4]
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. Calculations are performed using array N and the sign of the individual components of the output array ALPt should be based on the sign of array ALPe